# How to restore a device driver after it gets crashed programatically

Tags: c++

I have thousands of test cases and I am running them.After 30 testcases are run properly if the driver gets crashed suddenly then how to restore it through c/c++?

Comment: An OS device driver? Which OS?

Comment: It is highly operating system specific. On Linux I would suggest removing and re-installing the driver module, if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by crash? When on my computers a device driver crashes, I either get a blue screen or a kernel panic.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced driver crashes myself (had some fancy shader code running out of memory..). I can confirm that at least Windows 7 tries to restart drivers after crash by itself - usually it takes ~10 seconds. Anyway I have such experience only whit NVIDIA cards (last ATI I had froze whole system whit weird short sound loop on failure) and this will be more problematic for other OS too. In case you can live with some openGL 2.x, I think best choice would be virtual OS.. easy to reboot in case of failure, fast and fresh.

But to stay in topic, I believe this article is way to go for if you have Windows OS: [A C++ class wrapper to load/unload device drivers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31905/A-C-class-wrapper-to-load-unload-device-drivers). I don't see problem in shutting down and loading driver back (== restore) anyway, but in detecting crashed driver and meddling whit it while OS might be trying to restore it or when OS gets stuck..